# Configure dependency injection from middleware in dot net core

Tags: .net-core

I have a class that calls an external service which requires a token, and this is injected using the Settings class.

Now, depending on the request, I need to use one of two tokens.

I would like to use middleware to look at the incoming request to then configure what is injected into my service, but not sure this is possible?

Can I configure the DI from middleware?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can configure Dependency Injection from within middleware because DI is done (if you're using the DI system supplied with .NET Core) during the Container setup faze (take a look at your startup.cs class).

> I have a class that calls an external service which requires a token, and this is injected using the Settings class.
>
> Now, depending on the request, I need to use one of two tokens

Could you not get both tokens and pass them into your middleware's constructor? I did something similar (passing a configuration object into the middleware constructor) when I was creating my [OWASP secure headers middleware](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/08/03/net-core-middleware-configuration-options/) (it's part two in a now finished multipart series).

Could you take in the config and switch on something found within the request during your middleware's Invoke task?